# Conserve gravity action when overriding velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm developing a video game with Unity. I have a GameObject with a Rigidbody attached. I'm moving it overriding directly its velocity, which works great. The Y velocity is conserved to work as expected. But with angled walls, the applied horizontal velocity forces it to climb the wall and gravity's action won't take any effect. With 90 angled walls it works fine.

Is there any alternative to move the object without having to change directly its Rigidbody's velocity? Someone suggested me to use physics queries to determine if body can move instead of blindly change the velocity. The function I'm using right now is this one:

```
private void SetBodyVelocity()
{
    float verticalVelocity = _playerRigidbody.velocity.y;
    Vector3 newVelocity = _playerTransform.forward * _velocity;
    newVelocity.y = verticalVelocity;
    _playerRigidbody.velocity = newVelocity;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's been a while, but there's an `AddForce` [method on the rigid body](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). That allows you to specify the direction to apply the force via a vector

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I understand you are overriding the vertical velocity so you can keep it the way it was before but what's the goal here?, also, you should take a look at [ForceMode enum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@1.0/api/Unity.Physics.Extensions.ForceMode.html) which you can use on `AddForce` calls to state that you want a velocity change, since changing rigidbody velocity directly is not recommended